# Sending an array as hidden type in perl CGI

Tags: php, html, arrays, perl, cgi

I am attempting to send an array as a hidden type in per CGI. From [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=90127), I gathered that we can't send an array as is. Hence, I joined the array to form a string. Here's what the code looks  like:

```
 my @names;
 my $name, $value;
 foreach $pair (@pairs)
 {       ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
         $value =~ tr/+/ /;
         $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
         chomp($value);
         push (@names, $value);

 }
 pop (@names);
 print '<form action="test-plan.cgi"  method="POST">';
 print "<input name=\"typ\" value=\"red\" type=\"radio\" /><b>RED</b>";
 print "<input name=\"typ\" value=\"blue\" type=\"radio\" /><b>BLUE</b>";
 print "<input name=\"typ\" value=\"green\" type=\"radio\" /><b>GREEN</b>";

my $namestring = join("-",@names);
print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"these_names\" value=$namestring>";
print "<br /><br />$namestring";
print '<br /><input name="thisdata" type="submit" value="Select">';
```

So ideally, this is supposed to send the selected radio button and the string called `$namestring`.

This is what captures it:

```
print "$FORM{typ}";
my @names;
@names = split(/-/,$FORM{these_names});
print @names;
print "$FORM{these_names}";
```

Both these print statements gives only the first element in the array.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to quote value attribute

```
my $namestring = join("-",@names);
print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"these_names\" value=\"$namestring\">";
print "<br /><br />$namestring";
print '<br /><input name="thisdata" type="submit" value="Select">';
```